# Delete a duplicate list found inside an object C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an object called "`response`" that is type: `<LabelResponse>` that contains an object called "`items`" that is type: `IEnumerable<PostLabelResponse>`. This `PostLabelResponse` contains 2 strings called "`Key`" and "`Category`". The IEnumerable contains duplicated values of this `PostLabelResponse`. How can i delete this duplicates by the value "`Key`" and return the "`response`"?

I tried with `response.items.Distinct()` of `LinQ` but it didn´t work

Comment: It seems, that you should explain to .net which instnces of `PostLabelResponse` are equal. You can either implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods within `PostLabelResponse` or write and use a comparer, class that implements `IEqualityComparer<PostLabelResponse>` interface

Comment: so i have this: response:[ { key: "Small" , value: "Standard"},{ key: "Small" , value: "Standard"},{ key: "Medium" , value: "Standard"},{ key: "Big" , value: "Standard"},{ key: "Bulky" , value: "Bulky"},{ key: "Bulky" , value: "Bulky"}]

Comment: That code (please put code on an edit to the question, not as unformatted text in a comment) does not contain an attribute/property called "items"

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that your current `PostLabelResponse` which I assume being something like this

```
public class PostLabelResponse {
  ...

  public string Key {get; set;}
  public string Value {get; set;}

  ...
}
```

doesn't doesn't provide custom `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method and
that's why .Net uses *default* ones (which compare *references* not *values*).
If you want to compare *values*, say, `Key` and not `Value`, you can either implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode`:

```
    public class PostLabelResponse {
      public string Key { get; set; }
      public string Value { get; set; }

      ...

      public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
          return true;

        return obj is PostLabelResponse other &&
          Key == other.Key;
      }

      public override int GetHashCode() =>
        Key?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    }
```

From now on `Distinct()` starts using your rules (`Equals` and `GetHashCode`). Or you can implement a *custom comparer*:

```
    public sealed class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<PostLabelResponse> {
      public bool Equals(PostLabelResponse x, PostLabelResponse y) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
          return true;
        if (null == x || null == y)
          return false;

        return (x.Key == y.Key);
      }

      public int GetHashCode(PostLabelResponse obj) {
        return obj?.Key?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
      }
    }
```

which you *should specify* when using `Distinct`:

```
    .Distinct(new MyComparer())
```

Comment: The question is quite unclear but I interpreted it's distincted by Key only --> *How can i delete this duplicates by the value "Key"*

Comment: yes that is, sorry for my english

Comment: @LOU DAMN: I've changed the answer, now only `Key`s are compared

Answer (score 0):

.NET 6 introduced the [DistinctBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-6.0) method that can be used to find duplicates based on specific properties instead of the entire object. In previous versions, the same method is available in the [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) library. You can add the NuGet package, but the operator is so small you could easily add it to your project as source.

Assuming your class is :

```
public class PostLabelResponse {
  ...

  public string Key {get; set;}
  public string Value {get; set;}

  ...
}
```

You can retrieve distinct objects with :

```
var distinct=response.items.DistinctBy(x=>x.Key);
```

The operator code is really short :

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, 
    IEqualityComparer<TKey>? comparer=null)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));

    return _(); IEnumerable<TSource> _()
    {
        var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
        foreach (var element in source)
        {
            if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
                yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```